Mysterious Bare Strips on Artificial Grass
I brought a sample of artificial grass to see if we would like it or not. Something or some creature was eating or scratching strips of bare areas seemingly at night.  Each strip was approx. 2" wide.  The wide strips in the picture were made one 2" strip at a time building up to the wider strips shown.  The weirdest thing is that the strips were perfectly straight and always the same exact angle. After the majority were done, I rotated the turf 90 degrees and the strips appear at the exact same angle, but crosswise from the original.  The blades are down to the nubs and no visible "clippings" left behind. All this happened over about 45 days. No landscapers or visitors or wheeled things did this.  I even put out a motion detecting camera, but nothing. It looks mostly like scratching would be the cause, but by what? Our yard is visited by our dog, a neighbors cats, and the random squirrels and opossums and birds.  Does any animal use fake grass for nests?  Seriously curious about this.  It reminds me of the old "crop circles" only straight lines. Anybody?

Hi Randal, a picture would help

I tried, but picture was too large.

You can resize the picture to less than 2000 Kb with Windows Paint.
